# Sortable Container / Boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create boundaries for my Sortable Items. I've seen this question / answer:

[jquery sortable keep within container Boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204871/jquery-sortable-keep-within-container-boundary)

and tried to base my JS off of that but for whatever reason whenever I add a container around my UL I lose the top and bottom containment and the user can drag the items outside of the cotnainer:

[Correct Containment Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VzpBq/)

[My Wrong Containment Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khe0ymgr/1/)

Hey diddle diddle, here's code without fiddle:

**Working**

```js
    $(function() {      
        $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
           axis: 'y',
           containment: "parent" 
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

```css
ul{
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:70%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li{
    background:#ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px 5px;
    cursor:move;
}   
li:first-child{
    border-top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>second item</li>
    <li>third item</li>
    <li>fourth item</li>
    <li>fifth item</li>
</ul>
```

**Not Working**

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
   $( ".sort" ).sortable({
    axis:   'y',
    containerment: 'parent'
   }).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
ul{
    margin:20px 0 0 20px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:70%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li{
    background:#ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    padding:10px 5px;
    cursor:move;
}   
li:first-child{
    border-top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="sortWrapper">
    <ul class="sort">
        <li>first item</li>
        <li>second item</li>
        <li>third item</li>
        <li>fourth item</li>
        <li>fifth item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What's the difference between the two code blocks that makes the Non-Working Items leave the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typo'd 'containment' in the javascript of the second one.

Comment: *sigh* fml... I literally must have done this twice on my own project and when doing this fiddle... Thanks!

Comment: It's happened to me more than I'd like to admit. Sometimes all it takes is someone who hasn't been staring at it for awhile :)